# How can I "share" a network share over the internet to multiple operating systems?

Tags: networking, iis-7, internet, share

We have a network share accessible through our intranet that is widely used. This share has it's own set of fine tuned permissions.  I have been tasked with allowing A.D. authenticated  access to this share over the internet without the use of VPN. The internet access has to mimic the NTSF permissions in place on the share.

Another piece of the puzzle is that the access over the internet has to allow perusal of the share from Windows and Mac OS systems.

I had envisioned a web front end that would facilitate downloading to and uploading from the share via a web browser.

I'm trying to ask for some suggestions about what type of setup is necessary to achieve this.  I've done loads of testing and searching for solutions but I can't seem to get anything to work as I hope.

The web server that will be handing all of this is a Windows 2K8 box with IIS 7.

How can I allow the users to authenticate against Active Directory when coming from the internet even when coming from a Mac system?

I hope my question is not too broad, I'm sorry if I should have broken it up into multiple questions.  It all is just tied together in my head.

Thank you all for your time and aid.

Comment: One question: do the remote Mac systems require remote file locking so that Mac User editing letter.docx means local user B can't overwrite it until it's closed?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at running an SFTP server where the users can log in using their windows credentials.  For example http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=overview sounds suitable.